# Get correct *.aspx page from master for JS

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, url, webforms

I have a master page, where some script calls web method. My content pages inherited from intermediate base class, which realizes `[WebMethod] void SetSomeParam(bool flag)`. The problem is that script in master page don't know, which URL he need, `~/default1.aspx/SetSomeParam` or `~/default2.aspx/SetSomeParam`.
How to get correct URL from masterpage (and without codebehind, please).

---

UPDATE: `<%=Page.ToString()%>/SetSomeParam` provides output like `ASP.pages_default1_aspx/SetSomeParam`, but working URL must be `default.aspx/SetSomeParam`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to get the page name on client Side.

1. Extract it from window.location.pathname

   ```
   var url = window.location.pathname;  
   var myPageName = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);      
   alert(myPageName);
   ```
2. Use Path.GetFileName of Asp.net

   ```
   var page = '<%=Path.GetFileName(Request.Path)%>'
   ```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a valid url in master page JS like this:

```
var url = document.URL.replace(/\/?$/, '/') + 'SetSomeParam';
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the form action.

You should have a form element in your page like this:

```
<form id="form1" action="default1.aspx" method="post" name="form1">
```

You can retrieve the action with something like:

```
document.getElementById("form1").action
```